# Access bundled node.js module

Tags: node.js, express, npm

I wrote a small express.js based web app. I serve a manifest.webapp but express.js doesn't send the correct mime type. But because express.js bundles the mime module `require("mime").define(...)` has no effect. It defines the mime type for the wrong module!

Is there a way to access the mime module that is bundled with express.js? Or is there a way to tell npm (and nodejitsu) to not use the bundled modules of express.js?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that you can access bundled modules this way:

```
require("express/node_modules/mime").define({
    'application/x-web-app-manifest+json': ['webapp']
});
```

I don't know if this is the *proper* way to do it, but I use this for now.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are two ways to fix this.

#### Use a simple middleware

```
app.get('*.webapp', function (req, res, next) {
  res.header('Content-Type', 'application/x-web-app-manifest+json');
  next();
});
```

#### Monkey patching

Modify the response object and overwrite the `setHeader` method, where you can modify the response the actual value (it will work as a middleware).

```
var mime = require('mime');
mime.define({ 'application/x-web-app-manifest+json': [ 'webapp' ] });

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  var setHeader = res.setHeader;

  res.setHeader = function (field, val) {
    // you can be more strict here
    if (field === 'Content-Type') {
      val = mime.lookup(req.path);
    }

    return setHeader.call(this, field, val);
  }

  next();
});
app.use(express.static(__dirname + 'your-static-dir'));
```

So you'll use your own mime module instead of the bundled one.

**Update** static middleware is not using the `req.contentType` method.

Comment: This is pretty hacky. Is there really no cleaner solution? Is there really no way to install a version of express that doesn't bundle anything? Or that doesn't use the bundled modules if non bundled versions are available?

Comment: The second solution is a hack, I know. But the easiest way is the first solution, or you can also modify the installed mime module, but I would not recommend that.

Comment: Ok, that works. Still, this is pretty much a joke. What kind of web framework does not allow you to define a simple list of mime type mappings? WTF, why are these modules bundled? It only breaks everything and doesn't help with anything.

Comment: The comment about the monkey patch not working did refer to your first version. That did not work because as you said static does not use contentType.